# How do I get a Flex AdvancedDatagrid to display just one row?

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid, dataprovider, rowcount

I have an AdvancedDatagrid, whose dataProvider is an ArrayCollection that contains 1 row of displayable stuff.

Flex continues to display about 6 rows, the top one filled, the rest blank.

I've set the rowCount="1", with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I actually ran into this issue the other day.  It turns out I was setting the height of the AdvancedDataGrid to 100%, which overrides the rowCount property. If you check out the [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/AdvancedListBase.html#rowCount), it says "If the height of the component has been explicitly set, this property might not have any effect."

Answer (score 1):

you can set the row Count property value to 2 that is rowCount="2".. one row for the header other for the data ..

rty

Answer (score 0):

It will show blank rows for that you have to shorten the size of the grid